# Add a taxonomy type to a custom field using Field API

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I maid an edit to make problem more clear.
I'm creating a new field type using Field API (using hook_field_info , hook_field_schema ,hook_field_widget_info , ...)

my custom field should store different types of data like :

- Model  which is a text // No question here
- Speed which is a number // No question here
- Power again is a number // No question here
- **Make** , This my last type should be a taxonomy term , so it can be related to a vocabulary and gets a term from user and be rendered as a taxonomy term

  the question is "What steps should I take , to make it happen?"

because of some situations I have to use Field API , so modules like Field Collection ,etc wont help me.

Comment: have you considered using a [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) instead creating a custom field?

Comment: Because I should have to create too many field types (more than 200) and then attach them to many content types (95 different content types) so I'm writing a robot with c# to export types from data (are in json format) and make modules that after installing them all fields are created and attached to proper content types :D , so I need to use Field API

Comment: Here in Drupal [Field Types and Settings](https://www.drupal.org/node/1879542) , has mentioned that Taxonomy terme refrence can be used as a type but i still dont know how to handle it , any suggestion?

Comment: Where have you seen that you can reuse a field API field type inside another field type widget definition? I didn't think that was possible but if it was that would open up a whole world of new widget types we could make easily. I suspect you've just misunderstood, though, field API fields were not built to be reusable in that way